# Autorotate with a UINavigationController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, rotation

I am a little unclear on how to rotate views that are sitting on a UINavigationController.

I have overridden the UINavigationController object with one of my own that overrides:

> - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation { return YES; }

I have one view on the stack on the controller and that view is loaded from a xib with two views in it.  I want to switch from portrait to landscape.  Normally I would handle this by changing the view from within the nib files of the view itself.  Do I have to implement the rotational code within the Navigation Controller or just within my view code?

> - (void)willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
>                                                                                                 duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

That willAnimate code is what I'm used to using in the view itself, but I'm still not seeing the view being changed, and I'm thinking it may be that I need to access the view in the NavigationController and change that, or even override the same method in the Navigation Controller and do my view switching there.

Any suggestions?  I've never actually done this before and just found out the TabViewControllers and NavigationControllers are both portrait mode only by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't possible to change the view because I was trying to changes the RootView on the Navigation Controller.  I got around this by placing my own pseudo root view controller that never gets seen in the root spot on the Navigation stack.  I overrode a few of the navigation controls to account for this so the functionality would continue the same and I'd be able to change my desired perceived root view as I needed to.

A start in the right direction can be found in this link:

http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/changing-a-uinavigationcontroller’s-root-view-controller/